# redis.clients.jedis.search.SearchResult returns list with 10 elements

Tags: java, redis, jedis

SearchResult's  shows TotalResults 1000 but list size is 10.

```
    public static List<Document> queryonId(UnifiedJedis client) {
        Query q = new Query().addFilter(new Query.NumericFilter("id", 0, 10000)).setSortBy("id", true);
        SearchResult result = client.ftSearch("student-index-test", q);
        System.out.println("TotalResults :"+result.getTotalResults());
        System.out.println("List size: "+result.getDocuments().size());
        return result.getDocuments();
    }
```

Output of above code

```
TotalResults :10000
List size: 10
```

Please let me know what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ftSearch` method executes [FT.SEARCH](https://redis.io/commands/ft.search/) command. This command has an optional `LIMIT` argument which controls the pagination in the search results. Description of this argument states:

> LIMIT first num: Limit the results to the offset and number of results given. Note that the offset is zero-indexed. The default is 0 10, which returns 10 items starting from the first result.

As you are not putting your own paging value in the `Query` object using the `limit` method, you are getting the default number (10) of search results from the default position (0).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and it is working fine with limit. I have made following change in query  Query q = new Query().addFilter(new Query.NumericFilter("id", 0, 10000)).limit(0, 10000).setSortBy("id", true);